# In which system table does Postgres store FK cardinality?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, system-tables

I'm trying to reverse engineer a set of PG databases into a Data Model. I've found everything I need to define all the sub-models, tables, columns and FK constraints, but can't find anywhere that details whether the relation is 0:1, 1:many, 1:0..1 etc

I've looked in

```
pg_constraint
information_schema.check_constraint_routine_usage
information_schema.check_constraints
information_schema.constraint_column_usage
information_schema.constraint_table_usage
information_schema.domain_constraints
information_schema.referential_constraints
information_schema.table_constraints
information_schame.key_column_usage
```

but there's nothing (obvious) which details the cardinality.

Does anyone know where this can be found?

Comment: Can you not reverse-engineer this from `UNIQUE` constraints and `NOT NULL` constraints on the endpoints?

Comment: I probably can but I was (perhaps optimistically) hoping for something more pre-digested

Comment: That information isn't stored anywhere because it's not part of a FK constraint definition in SQL. You can only infer it from the nullability of the FK columns

Comment: Thanks both - that at least confirms I can stop searching

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key constraint *always* implements a one-to-many relationship between the destination table and the source table (where "many" could also be 0 or 1).

If the foreign key source has a unique constraint as well, there is a one-to-zero/one relationship.

Many-to many relationships are implemented as junction tables which have foreign keys referencing both participating tables.

Comment: It's not quite that simple - as @Jon of All Trades commented above, the nullability of the child table is also relevant, as the relationship can be optional or mandatory.

Comment: See, you have the answers. That's all you can glean from the database.

Comment: "A foreign key constraint *always* implements a one-to-many relationship between the destination table and the source table" - this is just wrong. FK constraints can represent 
`1:1` relationships in systems that support deferrable constraints (like Postgres) and `m:m` (without a linking table, using a single constraint) in systems that allow FKs to reference non-key columns in the principal table (such as MySQL).

Comment: @Dai I have corrected '"many" could also be 0)' to 'could also be 0 or 1', but other than that, I stand to what I wrote. I don't know what you mean by an m:m relationship, perhaps you can clarify.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe If your foreign key references a non-unique column or columns ("non-key column"), then you can have an m:n relationship without an intermediary table since the foreign key references multiple rows with a single value.

Comment: @DylanYoung But foreign keys always have to reference a unique or primary key constraint.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Not in MySQL, as the comment specifies.

Comment: "in systems that allow FKs to reference non-key columns in the principal table (such as MySQL)."

You're perfectly correct as far as PostgreSQL goes though :)